# What would be the correct way to communicate with redux-react application from another js module

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-framework

I have a complex form built with react-redux, and I need to know whether this form is valid from another javascript on the same page. Some jquery module.

The easiest way would be add `valid/not_valid` dynamic class to the react form, and to do something like

```
$('#myform').hasClass('valid')
```

But let's say that validation is not the only thing I need from this react app and I want to build a kind of interface for that with some getters. e.g.:

```
isValid(), getTitle, doSomethingElse methods.
```

what would be the right way to do that?

Comment: Since you are using redux, why not try redux-thunk? It enables you to implement conditional dispatch. If conditions fail, do not dispatch; otherwise, dispatch the action.

Comment: @Kiwi your comment is confusing and misleading in so many levels.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I am merely suggesting the author to try redux-thunk, instead of using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would store any information you need outside the React application within the store, then simply access the store within whatever jQuery you are writing. This would also work going the other direction, update the store with any particular data that the React application might need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

You can try saving the reference to the store that you instantiate in a global variable.

E.g. Let's say in your top-level React compnonent `App.js` you do

```
import MyMainStore from '..../MyMainStore';
.
.
.

<Provider store={MyMainStore}>...</Provider>

//Then finally also do 
_MyApp.ReduxStore = MyMainStore;
```

That way in the non-react/redux part of your app you can access the state via -

`_MyApp.ReduxStore.getState().myFormReducer.someExpectedState`

Look forward to hearing if that works for you.